# Handling multiple responses from Promises React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, promise

I have a few functions which return Promise responses. I am now trying to grab all of them and send all the data to the backend. However, I don't know how to grab them all. I have it like:

```
   componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
        this.getFunction1Data(ONEDAYINTERVAL), //returns an array of objects
        this.getFunction2Data(ONEDAYINTERVAL),
        this.getFunction3Data(ONEDAYINTERVAL),

    ]).then(([response1, response2, response3]) => {
        this.sendDataToServer(response3);
        // do stuff with your data
    }).catch(e => console.error);

}
```

But the issue here is, that somehow they're all mixed.

Example: sometimes reponse2 has data from all three functions, and sometimes response3 has all the data needed, while response2 is missing a few objects. How would I fix that? Should there be some function to form an array from all of the responses(with a check if element exists) or there is a way around?
Just for the double-check I am adding an example of a function here (others are identical):

```
 getFunction1Data(dateFrom) {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        AppleKit.initKit(KitPermissions.uploadBasicKitData(), (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return;
            }

            AppleKit.getSamples(dateFrom, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return resolve([]);
                }
                const newData = results.map(item => {
                    return { ...item, name: "Item1" };
                });
                const allData = [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...newData];
                this.setState({ ActivityItem: allData });
                resolve(allData);
            });
        })
    })
}
```

**UPDATE**
Second Function:

```
  getFucntion2Data(dateFrom) {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        AppleKit.initKit(KitPermissions.uploadBasicKitData(), (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return;
            }

            AppleHealthKit.getStepsSample(datefrom, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return resolve([]);
                }
                const newData = results.map(item => {
                    return { ...item, name: "StepsSample" };
                });
                this.setState(({ActivityItem}) => {
                    ActivityItem = [...ActivityItem, ...newData];
                    resolve(ActivityItem);
                    return { newData }
                });
            });
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem is here in `getFunction1Data`:

```
 const allData = [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...newData];
 this.setState({ ActivityItem: allData });
```

You're setting state based on existing state. Whenever you do that, you need to use the callback form of `setState`, not the form you pass state to directly. The reason is that [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and are "batched" when you make several changes between renders. So `this.state.ActivityItem` can be out of date when you build the new state you're giving to `setState`.

To use the callback form, don't have `allData` at all, and do:

```
 this.setState(({ActivityItem}) => {
     ActivityItem = [...ActivityItem, ...newData];
     resolve(ActivityItem);
     return { ActivityItem }
 });
```

The separate problem is that you have each call to `getFunction1Data` returning (via the promise) **all** of the gathered data, not just the data gathered by that call. It's not entirely clear to me what you want to do, but I'd lean toward having `getFunction1Data` return only the data it gathered (`newData`), not all the data, or to modify it so that it gets all of the information you want to get, not just one third of it, so you can call it just once.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot the reply. I finally got it, when I return only newData all the responses are starting to be exactly what I needed. Just one more question please, can you advice on how can I merge those three functions into one?  The only difference between them is in the different method call (instead of getSamples). I can update the question with it.

Comment: I have tried a couple of ways to do that but don't get how I should do resolve/return data in that case

Comment: @VladDemyan - Sorry, I'd missed that they were different functions. :-) So the only difference is `AppleKit.getSamples` vs. `AppleHealthKit.getStepsSample` vs. whatever the third one uses? You could pass those as a parameter: `getFunctionData(AppleKit.getSamples, ONEDAYINTERVAL)` and then `function getFunctionData(fn, dateFrom)` and use `fn` in the function. If you get an error because `this` during `getSamples` or `getStepsSample` isn't right, you'd add `bind` to the call: `getFunctionData(AppleKit.getSamples.bind(AppleKit), ONEDAYINTERVAL)`.

Comment: Works fine, appreciate your help!